# I want to gave image size in css

Tags: css

I want to gave image size in css.

Answer (score 1):

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

Comment: img {width: 100px; height: 100px;} to be precise?

Comment: @pixeltocode: for example; Yes. if you want apply to all images.

Comment: Best thing would be to add a specific class to any images that you want to do that to like .img_100wh {width:100px; height:100px;}